# Upload image to FTP from PictureBox

Tags: c#, ftp

- in my C# desktop application there is picturebox and loaded with an
  image.
- i just want to upload this image to FTP without save image to
  local pc.
- how do i do that ?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I Think You Are Trying To Upload A Image File To FTP
This Code Is Work For You

You Have To Crete A FTP Web Request

FtpWebRequest request =(FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.yourftp.com");

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("username","password");

string flepath="Locationoffile";

FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(filePath);

byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];

stream.close();

request.ContentLength=buffer.Length;

Stream requestsream=request.GetRequestStream();

requestStream.Write(buffer,0,buffer.Lenght);

requestStream.Close();

FtpWebResponse response=(FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

response.Close();

Comment: There is no "Locationoffile" because the image is not on local. its loaded in a PictureBox.